# Get oracle output parameter using OracleCommand

Tags: asp.net, oracle, system.data.oracleclient

I have a oracle stored procedure which will return a value. I need to get the OUTPUT value in my C# program. I need to know how we can get the OUTPUT parameter using the OracleCommands AddWithValue method.

The way i have written now is:

```
 OracleCommand Ocmd = new OracleCommand(_StoredProcedure, OraCon);
    Ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            Ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Filed1", "Value1");

            Ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OUTPUTParam","").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    OraCon.Open();
    int RecivedDetID = Ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    OraCon.Close();

    return Ocmd.Parameters[_OutParam].Value.ToString();
```

I know the OUTPUTPARAm how i have called is wrong. How can i achieve it using the 
AddWithValue method of the OracleCommand. I dont want to use the OracleCommands Add method where we need to specify the Type also.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you set the SIZE property on the parameter before executing. With output parameters in Oracle, the specified size acts as a buffer. If the buffer isn't set, it is 0 so you don't get the value from the database.

```
var param = Ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OUTPUTParam","").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param.Size = 255;
```

The rest is good!

Comment: Which version of the OracleDataAccess are you using?

Comment: I mean as far as 10g/11g. The version this works in is 10.2.0.100 or higher. Also, are you using the .net 1.x or 2.x assemblies? you can find this information by right clicking on the Reference in the project and clicking properties.